# Adding image icon on buttons?

Tags: java, image, button, icons

I am making a board game and I have a 3 x 10 buttons on the board. How can I add a image icon on the buttons to represent the board pieces?

I only need it for the first 10 buttons.

Comment: if we can talking about Swing JButton, then better would be update your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Which graphics library? AWT? Swing? SWT?

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(yourFile);
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(im);
JButton b = ...;
b.setIcon(ii);
```

Comment: Tips: 1) It seems as though these icons are very much something that when deployed will be an 'embedded application resource' - i.e. in a Jar.  For that reason, they will not be accessible as `File` objects as implied by `yourFile`. 2) Resources in Jars are accessible by `URL` obtainable from `Class.getResource(String)` 3) `ImageIcon` has a constructor that accepts an `URL` (it is not blocking, like the `ImageIO.read()` method, but `JButton` implements an `ImageObserver` - which is better) 4) Button has 2 constructors that accept an icon.

Comment: 5) To format code snippets, select the code and click the `{}` button above the question/answer posting/editing form.  They appear with color context, better than `pre`/`code` wrappers.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

JButton Button;
Button=new JButton(new ImageIcon("image_path"));